# How to measure energy stored in a battery

Tags: batteries, storage

I have just designed a solar panel prototype, how do i measure the energy stored in the battery that is connected to it? 
What device can i use? 
i will place the solar panels with car battery attached in the open for 3 days. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This would sound silly, but to give you a rough idea:

Just connect a new 500W bulb across the battery. Keep it on till the light dies down.
500W * (the time in seconds it keeps glowing) should give you the approximate idea of the energy stored in the battery

Answer (score 1):

For some rechargeable batteries, filled capacity is directly related to voltage. As it is recharged, the voltage goes up, up to a certain point, depending on the chemistry of the battery.

Comment: Presumably that's the open-circuit voltage, with solar cell charger *disconnected*?